# Fill a WrapPanel from a List

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, wrappanel

Is there any way of dynamically binding a list buttons to a `WrapPanel` as well as their events?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not too sure if this is correct for what you are wanting to do, but it sounds very similar:

- [WPF - Fill a WrapPanel from a List](http://discoveringdotnet.alexeyev.org/2009/03/fill-wrappanel-from-list-wpf.html)

The XAML from the link above is as follows:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="activitiesControl" Margin="10">
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <WrapPanel  Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" 
                    FlowDirection="LeftToRight" IsItemsHost="true">
            </WrapPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Style="{DynamicResource ActionButton}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5" 
                Content="{Binding Value}" Width="200" 
                Command="{Binding Path=ViewModel.ActionTypeCommand, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,     
                AncestorType=local:CustomerEditView}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Key}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I'm sure I'm showing my ignorance here (beginner to WPF and Xaml at the moment), but I can't see how ItemsControl finds the property ItemsSource (which I believe is mentioned in the source article).

Comment: I'm an idiot. For anyone who's new to WPF and wants to avoid my confusion, ItemsControl has a property (ItemsSource) that can be assigned at runtime, NOT via a property on the associated VM. Presumably, this also means that adding the property `ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"` would probably work...